# Conversion Error when trying to create dictionary with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I'm writing a program in C# and I have a problem.

```
this.ProcessCache = new Dictionary<ProcessCacheEntry, Process>(Process.GetProcesses().Select(p => new KeyValuePair<ProcessCacheEntry, Process>(new ProcessCacheEntry(p), p)));
```

This is the error I get:

> Error CS1503
> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<CookieProjects.ProcessWatcher.ProcessCacheEntry, System.Diagnostics.Process>>' to 'int'

but `this.ProcessCache` is `Dictionary<ProcessCacheEntry, Process>` not int!

Comment: small and not related tip for you:
just because you can put all the code in one line, doesn't mean you should, it is terrible to read

Comment: I would use the [ToDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_ToDictionary__3_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Func___0___2__) method, it should be shorter.

Comment: Dictionary<TKey, TValue> has eight constructors. One of them requires you to pass a variable of type int, called "capacity". Because the arguments you put in the Dictionary's constructor do not match any of the eight constructors, the compiler took a guess that you were using the one that takes an int, and it's giving you a compile error because you didn't pass an int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use the ToDictionary instead of the new KeyValue constructor

how to initalize:

```
var allProcess = Process.GetProcesses();
var yourDictionary = allProcess.ToDictionary(ToProcessCacheEntry);
```

ToProcessCacheEntry method:

```
private ProcessCacheEntry ToProcessCacheEntry(Process process)
{
    return new ProcessCacheEntry(process);
}
```

Comment: You have edited your answer until it doesn't work anymore. Also, your static method is useles.

Comment: @Steeeve the answer before the edits add the second param to the ToDictionary, which is useless.
regarding the static function, 
the fact that it is static is useless (just tried that code on a new project, i will edit), regarding the separation of creation, I like it that way, so the code would be more readable, so I think it looks better,  in addition to that, that's one more place that you can unit test things

Comment: Ther is no overload of the ToDictionary extension method, that accepts a single Func<T>. So it simply can't work.

Comment: @Steeeve Yes there is
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_ToDictionary__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__

Comment: You are right. I had expected something like a process-id as key, not ProcessCacheEntry objects. But reading the question one more time, yes, it gives the requested dictionary.